# migrate passwords from nopcommerce to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, passwords, nopcommerce, migrate

Hello I have around 7000 users in a nopcommerce platform, and I want to migrate all these to a new wordpress installation.

I have the passwords in a database.

These are encrypted in nopcommerce.

Once I integrate these passwords, wordpress doesn't recognize them.

What is the procedure to migrate passwords from a platform (in this case nopcommerce to wordpress?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

wordpress use md5 type for password hashing and nopcommerce use SHA-1 with salt.
read the article below : 
https://www.nopcommerce.com/blog/101-nopcommerce-wordpress-integration.aspx

it's about wordpress-nopcommerce integration which you can install on your nopcommerce part to sync customers with wordpress part

this is for your old user. for newly added users you can go to Configuration → Settings → Customer Settings and set password format to clear, so it will save password same as what user entered and after that you can insert to wordpress easily.

Comment: It will save new accounts password in clear format not old accounts